# A problem from Munkres' Analysis on manifolds 16.3

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

The problem is :[image]

$C^r$ function $g_{x_0}: U_{x_0} \to \mathbb R$ such that $g_{x_0}=f$ on $U_{x_0}\cap S$.
Then, consider the collection of sets $\mathscr{A}=\{U_{x\in S}\}$ ，and let $A=\bigcup_{x\in S}U_x$ ，this is a cover of $S$. Then by the theorem of 16.3 in the book, there exists a smooth partition of unity $\{\phi_x\}$ which is dominated by $\mathscr{A}$。The $x$ below $\phi_x$ is to mean that $\text{supp}\ \phi_x$ is in $U_x$ which is a neighborhood of $x\in S$ .
Then consider $$h(x')=\sum\limits_{x\in S}\phi_x(x')g_x(x')$$ where $x'$ is the element in $A$
Is this the desired extended function for $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$? My confusion is, for $U_x$, they can overlap.
If $x'$ in $S$ , and it is in a overlap of $U_{x_1}$ and $U_{x_2}$ (and even more $U$ )，then it doesn't matter since $g_{x_1}=g_{x_2}=f$ this time, and this time$$h(x')= \sum\limits_{x\in S}\phi_x(x')g_x(x')=f(x')\sum\limits_{x\in S} \phi_x(x')=f(x')$$ and this makes sence.
However, if $x'$ is in $A-S$  and it is in a overlap of $U_{x_1},U_{x_2}$ , since now $x'$ is not in $S$ , $g_{x_1}$ and $g_{x_2}$ can be not equal to each other. Then by the local finiteness: $$\begin{align*}
h(x')&= \sum\limits_{x\in S} \phi_x(x')g_x(x')
\end{align*}$$ is a finite sum of products of $g_x$ and $\phi_x$, and I don't know what is the answer to this sum.
My questions are:

1. Is the $h$ defined above the right answer to the problem?
2. If it is, for $x'$ that is not in $S$ , what is the value of $h(x')$ ?.